# Wiremock stub working like ECHO

Tags: spring-mvc, wiremock

my JS application is using wiremocks to mock backend calls. Is it possible to create such Wiremock definition in order to create echo service (the body JSON content of response shoould be the same as  body JSON content of request).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with the new response templating feature: http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/